# Unsigned Binary String to Unsigned Binary Integer

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, radix, bit

I have created a working **Getter** that :

> Returns the stored decimal value as an unsigned binary string bits
>   wide

```
string GetUnsignedBase2(int base_10, int bits) {

string base_2;
//Find binary
int remainder = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != bits; i++) {
    remainder = base_10 % 2;
    base_2.insert(0, to_string(remainder));
    base_10 /= 2;

}
return base_2;
```

But now I am trying to create a **Setter** for it that :

> Updates the value of the stored decimal integer by interpreting the
>   parameter base 2 as an unsigned binary integer

I am unsure how to do this, so far I have:

```
void BaseConverter::SetUnsignedBase2(string base_2)
{

}
```

Comment: That's pretty smart looking code so far. Textbook quality. What are you stuck on?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Well, I never really learned much about binary conversions, so I am unsure what it exactly means to update the result of my Get method by interpreting the paramater as an unsigned binary integer, is this some other type of conversion?

Comment: Your first function takes an integer and returns a string showing the binary representation of that integer (zero padding it or cutting it off to "bits" bits if necessary). The second function needs to reverse that: interpreting the characters in the string as binary digits and returning their value as an int. (So it should return an int instead of void, BTW). That is, just reverse the logic you wrote in the Getter function.